# How to get the Image URL from Picture Library and folders in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

I want to get the Image URL from picture library and from the folders inside the library in SharePoint. I have tried both internal names ows_FileRef and ows_EncodedAbsUrl.

For ows_FileRef it is showing id and # in front of the image url.

For ows_EncodedAbsUrl it is showing as undefined.

Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Please provide your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to iterate through folders as per your requirement:

```
SPFolder folder = ListPicture.RootFolder.SubFolders["picLib"];
```

And then you can use SpQuery to get the data:

```
string SPtestQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>"
    + GlobalConfiguration.Current.Items[Constants.ConfigurationKeys.ContentTypeID]
    + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";                                                                                                

string SPTestFields = string.Concat(
    "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>",
    "<FieldRef Name='GalleryImage'/>",                                           
    "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>");

string listUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, "picLib");
```

You can get the data in datatable.